# Restricting Containers with Generics

Tags: java, generics, class-design

I'm currently in the process of designing the class hierarchy for a simulation project. It is going to be a discrete-event simulation of a tree of `Element` instances. For brevity (and because I'm only interested in the generics part of the problem) I'll only present sketches of the classes / interfaces here, so the syntax will not be perfect. To have something to start with, an element might look like this:

```
public abstract class Element {
    private Set<Element> children = new HashSet<Element>();
    public Element getContainer();
    public Collection<Element> getChildren() {
       return Collections.unmodifiableSet(children);
    }
    public Position getPosition();
    protected void add(Element e) { children.add(e); }
    protected void remove(Element e) {children.remove(e); }
}
```

The definition of `Position` does not really matter, and what the other methods are supposed to do is self-explanatory I hope. To make things mildly interesting we throw another interface into the pool:

```
public abstract class Solid extends Element {
    public Size getSize();
}
```

Again, the exact meaning of `Size` does not matter, a `Solid` is just supposed to be a physical object which fills space in the simulated world. Now that we have solid object we may want to stack them on top of each other, so here's a `Stack`:

```
public abstract class Stack extends Solid {
    public void add(Solid s); // <- trouble ahead!
}
```

And here's where the trouble starts. I really want only instances of `Solid` to be added to the `Stack`. That's because it's difficult to stack objects that have no size, so the `Stack` will need something which has a `Size`. Therefore I rework my `Element` to allow expressing this:

```
public abstract class Element<E extends Element<?>> {
    private final Set<E> children = new HashSet<E>();
    public Element<?> getContainer();
    public Collection<E> getChildren();
    public Position getPosition();
    public void add(E e);
    public void remove(E e);
}
```

My intention here is to express that an `Element` can have a restriction on which (sub-)types of `Element` it may contain. So far this works and all. But right now I felt the need to have an restriction on the *container* of an `Element`. What does that look like?

```
public interface Element<E extends Element<?,?>, C extends Element<?, ?>>
```

Or does it go more like this:

```
public interface Element<E extends Element<?,C>, C extends Element<E, ?>>
```

I'm starting to feel a bit fuzzy about this, and there's more to the game:

- there have to be "Ports" (`Input` and `Output`) which transfer Elements from one container to another. I'll have to throw some generics magic at these, too.
- there's a GUI editor for the models on my todo list. So I'll have to make these checks available at runtime, too. So I guess there will be type literals and something like `public boolean canAdd(Element<?, ?> e)` the editor will have to rely on. Because this method is so important I'd like to have it an `final` method of the `Element` class, so no drunken developer can get it wrong at 4am.
- It would be cool if subclasses of `Element` could decide for themselfs which `Collection` class they are using, because from some of the a `LinkedList` or whatever seems a perfect fit.

So here are my questions:

- Am I re-inventing the wheel? Which library does that for me?
- Can and should I tackle this with generics? (if the answer is yes: some hints on the implementation are very welcome)
- Could this be a bit over-engineered?
- Are there a better title or tags for this question? :-)
- (just drop your opinion here)

Comment: Here's a thought for you.  The purpose of generics in java is to prevent ClassCastException.  full stop.  That is the only thing they do in a sane manner.  If you're trying to use them for something else, that way lies madness.

Comment: "that way lies to madness", haha.. before I understood type erasure, I was attempting all sorts of wild tricks with generics, but soon learned that, for the most part, creative uses of generics were doomed to failure.. and if it gets to looking really crazy like Element<E extends Element<?,C>, C extends Element<E, ?>> you should be skeptical of using them. It's too hard to conceptualize these uses.

Comment: @Affe The purpose of what I try to do here ultimately boils down to preventing CCEs. Think about the stack, which can only work on Elements that have a getSize()--that's a Solid. So if I use generics to express this, the compiler will make sure it's ok. Otherwise I'll have to cast and find some other way to check if that cast is valid.

Comment: As a few people who answered have also indicated, from your post it looks very much like you're trying to define object relationships/template methods :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still a bit fuzzy as to what you're trying to do, but if you want to run with this all the way to its logical conclusion, I'm seeing something like this:

```
/**
@param P parent
@param C child
@param S self
*/
interface Element<P extends Element<?, S, P>, 
        C extends Element<S, ?, C> ,
        S extends Element<P, C, S>> {
    public P getParent();
    public Collection<C> getChildren();
}
```

That expresses (I think) all your constraints: my parent must be something that can have me as a child, and my children must be something that can have me as a parent.

Implementations would include:

```
/** An agglomeration of stacks: no parent */
class Agglomeration extends Element<?, Stack, Agglomeration> {…}

/** A stack of solids */
class Stack extends Element<Agglomeration, Solid, Stack> {…}

/** A solid in a stack: no children */
class Solid extends Element<Stack, ?, Solid> {…}
```

I don't have a Java IDE open right now, though, so I can't confirm this will actually compile -- I have a feeling that the compiler will complain about those question marks, and try to drag you into something like

```
class Agglomeration extends Element<? 
    extends Element<? 
        extends Element<? 
            extends...
```

You can get around that, though, if you separate `Parent` and `Child` into separate interfaces (one with `getChildren()` and one with `getParent()`), so `Agglomeration` only implements the first and `Solid` only implements the second, while `Stack` implements both.

It might be more trouble than it's worth, but run with it for a while and see where it takes you. :)

Comment: As far as I can tell now, that notion of "self" was in a very true sense the missing "link" with what I had until now. I had to make minor changes to the interface you suggested, I'm currently playing with `interface Elem<P extends Elem<?, S, ?>,C extends Elem<S, ?, ?>, S extends Elem<P, C, S>> { /* ... */ }` to see how far it takes me. :-) Thanks a lot so far!

Answer (score 1):

Just some random remarks:

Instead of `Collection<E>` you may or may not want `Collection<? extends E>`.

I'm quite sure, you want start with `Element<E extends Element<**E**>` since you want to capture the type of this (just look at java.lang.Enum). So you need maybe something like   `Element<E extends Element<E,C>, C extends Element<C, ?>>`
It may get too complicated, both for you and for the compiler (maybe it's got better, but some time ago I got some really strange errors when trying too hard).

Maybe the methods Element.add and Stack.add are in fact different methods? Adding children to Stack means sort of stacking them, adding them to an arbitrary Element may mean something completely different?

> It would be cool if subclasses of Element could decide for themselfs which Collection class they are using, because from some of the a LinkedList or whatever seems a perfect fit.

A method like `Collection<C> makeCollection()` called in ctor of the base class could do. However, using LinkedList is wrong most of the time (its bad space locality and high space overhead makes it so slow so that it's advantages may be ignored).

> So I'll have to make these checks available at runtime, too.

So you need to construct the instances using `Class<E>` parameter.

> return Collections.unmodifiableSet(children);

This way you're returning a live-view of children. Consider using com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(children) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm basing this answer on my understanding of your design. If I'm wrong in my understanding, please let me know!

The main purpose of generics is to ensure type-safety and not object relationships (as far as I know, anyway). It seems like you can enhance the relationship between objects by ensuring type-safety, but ultimately the purpose is to ensure type-safety (so that you're not sticking something where it doesn't belong).

In your abstract class, you've provided a method called `add`. This means that anything that extends this abstract class must implement `add`. Now later, you're imposing a restriction on `add` saying that you can only `add` `Solid` objects (which is a subclass of `Element`). But in doing that, you're violating the contract of the abstract class, which says that an `Element` (or a subclass thereof) can be added to the set.

So there are two options. You either have to rethink your design (maybe `add` should not be provided in the abstract class?). Your other option is to throw a runtime exception (`UnsupportedOperationException` perhaps) when you try to `add` an object that has no size, and also provide an inspection method (like `canAdd`) that lets the developer know if the specific object can be added.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this line:

```
public interface Element<E extends Element<?,?>, C extends Element<?, ?>>
```

made me feel that yes, this is certainly over-engineered.

Of course there are many ways out of the situation but the one that sounds appropiate to me is to use the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern instead of inheritance (not everywhere, only where you feel the original design is fraying) and maybe that way generics will fit in better too.